# docker-compose cannot access to database port

Tags: docker, spring-boot

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8_server-jre_unlimited
# copy application
COPY server.jar /opt/test/
COPY application.yml /opt/test/

# expose server ports
EXPOSE 8080 18080

# Run via dumb-init
WORKDIR /opt/test
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "server.jar"]
```

**docker-compose files:**

```
services:
  backend-server:
    image: test.com/server:latest
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database-server
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
        - "127.0.0.1:18080:18080"
  database-server:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD testtest
```

**application property file:**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    # use default user/database created by PostgreSQL Docker image upon startup
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: testtest
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

When I run the docker-compose up, it will create a database container and an application container which connects to the database container.

But the spring application container encounters some problem during bootup with error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

`docker container ls` shows the database is running, and I can access it if I run the spring application directly.

```
a295bfd16e2c        postgres:9.6        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   127.0.0.1:5432->5432/tcp   server_database-server_1
```

So what would be the problem that I messed up?

**Solution I found**

```
services:
  backend-server:
    image: test.com/server:latest
    build: .
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://database-server/postgres
    depends_on:
      - database-server
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 18080:18080
  database-server:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD testtest
```

But I still cannot access the application from `localhost:8080` of my computer, even the log of the container says

> 2018-10-31 15:02:40.881  INFO 1 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s):
>   8080 (http) with context path ''
>
> 2018-10-31 15:02:40.881  INFO 1 --- [           main]
>   com.test.server.Application         : Started Application in
>   12.823 seconds (JVM running for 13.235)

Comment: Postgres is not in your spring container, so is not reachable on `localhost`. Depending on if you have any other networking going on (which I don't see from the compose file as it doesn't look complete?), try `url: jdbc:postgresql://database-server/postgres` instead.

Comment: `Connection attempt failed: UnknownHostException`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to modify your docker-compose.yml file as given below and test it

```
services:


backend-server:
    image: test.com/server:latest
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database-server
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 18080:18080
  database-server:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD testtest
```

Comment: `69c8ec1a5783        postgres:9.6                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                             server_database-server_1` The ip changed from 127 to 0, but it generates still the same error in the application.

Comment: can you update the spring DB url as url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Answer (score 0):

```
services:
  backend-server:
    image: test.com/server:latest
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database-server
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" #change to 8080:8080 without ""and by default set to local so you dont need add local ip
        - "127.0.0.1:18080:18080"  #change to 18080:18080 without ""and by default set to local so you dont need add local ip
  database-server:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432" #change to 5432:5432 without ""and by default set to local so you dont need add local ip
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD testtest
```