# Cannot access a running spring boot application docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I'm running a [spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53084886/5265472) in the background as an API server, but I cannot access it from `localhost:8080`.

**Container status**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
2c494c8304e0        corpobids.com/server:latest   "java -jar server.jar"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18080->18080/tcp   server_api-server_1
8d1883ebcb0b        postgres:9.6                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                             server_database-server_1
```

The ports are already exposed and mapped. The application is running fine in the container.

> 2018-10-31 15:25:21.255  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s):
> 8080 (http) with context path ''
>
> 2018-10-31 15:25:21.256  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> com.api.server.Application         : Started Application in
> 13.861 seconds (JVM running for 14.25)

How do I call the API of the application from my host computer?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED`

Comment: What's your platform ? If you are running docker in a docker-machine (ex Docker toolbox on Windows) you need to use the ip of the docker-machine instead of localhost.

Comment: I use Fedora, and docker-compose up to run the image.

Comment: Try http://0.0.0.0:8080 in your browser and http://127.0.0.1:8080 to see if they work. If they work, please post your docker running command or docker-compose file. Why did you expose 2 ports : 8080 and 18080?

Comment: @Adina it does not work, same error message in the browser `This site can’t be reached`.

Comment: ok, the controller that should respond to "/" ?

Comment: I resolved the problem by changing the port in my `application.yml` file from 127 to 0.0.0.0